# Taiwan visitor visa for Indian passport with ECR (Emigration Check required) category

Tags: visas, india, taiwan, ecr

I want to apply for a visit visa for Taiwan. I am an Indian passport holder with ECR (Emigration check required Category). Do I need to submit any extra documents?

Does a Passport with ECR category create any problem while leaving India and entering Taiwan for visit purpose? I will stay in Taiwan for 1 month.

Comment: ECR is only if you are traveling for work to the Middle East.

Answer (score 4):

First, ECR/ECNR is only relevant for **Indian** authorities (you require clearance from them), not for foreign authorities.

Second, as stated by Burhan Khalid, it is only relevant if you travel for employment, and [only to 17 specific countries](http://boi.gov.in/content/encrecr) (not just Middle East). Taiwan is not in this list, and you're only applying for a visit.

Indian immigration would need to see your roundtrip ticket to Taiwan.